# Facebook framework in iOS4/5?

Tags: ios, facebook

I can add the new facebook framework to my project with the new XCode 4.5.2 but I guess it won't work? I don't have access to a device with iOS 4 nor 5 (have simulator of 5). I only need to do Facebook share (post a status from my app).

What strategy should I use to make sure I get facebook share in all platforms (iOS 4, ios 5, ios6)? Right now we are using FacebookManager

https://github.com/ryotarai/FacebookManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal Facebook iOS SDK, from Facebook, will work perfectly fine on all versions of iOS. You should just use that. It will use native auth on iOS 6 and fall back gracefully to switching to the FB app or Safari as appropriate.